# php array implode for insert

Tags: php, html, implode

I'm passing an html array to php using jquery serializearray() function.

In php I can access the array using $_POST like

```
 $a = $_POST['htmlarray']
```

The html array, however, is an array of arrays like so

```
 htmlarray[] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18]]
```

I want to format the variable $a so that I can insert all the html array values in one single insert query like

```
 INSERT INTO table
 (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6)
  VALUES
    (1,2,3,4,5,6),
   (7,8,9,10,11,12),
    (13,14,15,16,17,18)
```

I know I have to use an implode function, can anyone show how this could be done.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php AND/OR http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php SO is not meant for questions like this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what an html array is, but try the following:

```
$a = $_POST['htmlarray'];

// unserialize $a

// build sql query up to '...VALUES '

foreach ($a as $row) {
   $sql .= '(';
   $sql .= implode(',', $row);
   $sql .= ')',
}
```

This should iterate through the arrays and append all your rows to the string. Note, however, that this code does not take care of SQL Injections at all! Not to be meant for production.